# How to keep a userform open when closing other instances of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hope someone can help - I have a Userform that opens on launch of the excel file (Test.xlsm) and hides the workbook from prying eyes.  The workbook can become visible for editing by a button click and password entry from the userform.  Everything is working fine - UNTIL - you open another instance of excel.  Once you finish with it and close any secondary instance of excel, it also either 
1. closes the userform, or 
2. shows the excel workbook behind the userform.  Neither of these is what I want.  I need the userform to remain open and I need the workbook associated with it to remain hidden until called.

Question - is there some code that will prevent other instances of excel from doing what it is doing, or am I dreaming.
I found some code (below) that the writer said done exactly what i am after, but all I got was global errors.

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Open()

    If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then Application.Visible = False

    Workbooks("test.xlsm").Windows(1).Visible = False

    UserForm1.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

BTW - the code for the workbook open is

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set Thiswb = Me.Application
    Application.Visible = False
    Staff_Contacts.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For usecase you described, I would propose you something similar to this solution:

```
Sub Workbook_open()
    Dim wrong_attempts As Integer
    wrong_attempts = 0
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Start1:
    If wrong_attempts > 4 Then
        MsgBox "You've entered wrong password too many times. File will now be closed"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sheet.Delete
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    InputBoxVariable = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter password to access this document", Title:="Authorization required", Default:="")
    If InputBoxVariable = "12345" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Else
        wrong_attempts = wrong_attempts + 1
        GoTo Start1
    End If
End Sub
```

In this example it is assumed that sheet2 should be protected. On the very load of the document, phantom sheet will be created, and after successful login, it will be deleted and sheet2 should be visible again. In addition, if someone enters wrong password 5 times, file closes automatically.

Fair notice, I've used InputBox out here, so password is not masked, if you want to mask password as well, you will have to make brand new form with button and textbox.

Comment: Not quite what I’m looking for, but thanks for the valuable input.  I’m trying to make this workbook stand alone if that’s possible - not affected in anyway by opening or closing other workbooks.

Comment: To be quite honest, from what you've described, this really works like a charm, and it is not affected by any other workbooks (in the mother of fact, you cant even open any new workbooks, until you finish with this one). I've alerted a bit my code in the example above, and how it works live, you can see out here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=43432369229684673456

Comment: Cheers and thanks, I’ll check it out and see if I can work it into mine.